# How to populate db with sample data using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP/MySQL. For those who populate your db with sample data before launching, how do you do it while staying true to the column's data type? For example, here's what my table looks like:

```
+-------------+------------------+
| Field       | Type             |
+-------------+------------------+
| speaker_id  | int(10) unsigned |
| name        | char(200)        |
| writeup     | text             |
| is_employee | tinyint(1)       |
+-------------+------------------+
```

All values will be inserted using a bulk insert by adding to the sql string `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (...), (...), etc.` to keep the db resource use low.

Comment: you mean like without knowing the column's data type in advance? otherwise it would be a normal insert data into the db stuff.. however you just have to generate some random data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load contents into your DB using a txt, CSV or Excel file

Command is

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.csv' INTO TABLE test(field1,field2,field3,...)
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP that you are using to insert/update the data will need know about the allowed types and validate it before running the query.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP class: [DB Populator](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6416-PHP-Populate-a-MySQL-database-with-random-data.html) may help you